# Ejecutar un evento cada 2 dias

Tags: mysql

Hola a todos me gustaría crear un evento que eliminara cada dos días las tuplas de una tabla que tengan una fecha de dos días anteriores a cada cuando se ejecute el evento.
La tabla tiene 4 campos que son id,nick,correo y fecha. Entonces cuando el evento se ejecute por ejemplo hoy a las 12:00 debe eliminar todos los registros que tengan fecha de hace dos días hasta la fecha actual.
Estoy teniendo problemas con el modo seguro, lo intento quitar pero no me deja. Pongo el código:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `eliminar`  
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS '2022-01-11 19:50:00'  
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE DO 
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
DELETE FROM Desbloquear 
WHERE fecha < curdate();
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```

Aquí se ejecuta cada minuto para probarlo únicamente. ¿ El modo seguro solo es en el workbrench? Si lo quito no afectara a la base de datos. ¿Es seguro quitarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Bueno al final encontré una solución. No se si es la más adecuada pero hice una subselect para sacar los id que quería eliminar. La he probado y me funciona. Supongo que habrá formas más eficientes. Pongo como lo he dejado:

```
drop event eliminar;


CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `eliminar`  
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS '2022-01-11 20:32:00'  
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE DO 
DELETE FROM Desbloquear 
WHERE idDesbloquear in (select idDesbloquear WHERE fecha < curdate())
```